# Number of ways to pick a selection of coins

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to pick a selection of coins from $1 worth of identical pennies, 1 dollar worth of identical nickels, and 1 dollar worth of identical dimes if you select a total of 16 coins?

I know I start off with C(16+3-1,16), but I can't seem to factor the fact that you can't have 16 dimes.

Comment: You should not write questions in a way that begin in the title and then continue in the body. You brought pennies into play in  the title and then nickels and dimes in the body. This is what confused @AndreNicolas. Give the question a title, and then state the _full_ question in the body.

Comment: Noted. I didn't realize that was the proper way to format my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Stars and Bars, getting $\binom{18}{16}$, but then we must subtract the forbidden combinations that involve $11$ to $16$ dimes.

With $11$ dimes there are $6$ possibilities ($0$ to $5$ nickels, the rest pennies). With $12$ dimes there are $5$ possibilities, and so on down to $1$ possibility for $16$ dimes. Thus the total is $\binom{18}{16}-(6+5+\cdots+1)$.

Comment: Ummm from my understanding of the textbook, another way to rephrase the question is this: how many different ways can you pick 16 coins if you have: 100 pennies, 20 nickels, and 10 dimes at your disposal.

Comment: To be fair, the edit log seems to indicate the game always had nickels as well as pennies and dimes.

Comment: OP's original problem had all three types of coin. Unfortunately OP wrote the question in way that starts in the title and continues in the body, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. Let $d$ represent the number of dimes you choose. This number is distinguished from the other two, because it can't go past $10$, but the other two can go up to $16$. Let $n$ represent the number of nickels. With $d$ dimes chosen, you can have $0$ through $16-d$ nickels. Then the number of pennies is determined as $16-d-n$.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{d=0}^{10}\sum_{n=0}^{16-d}1&=\sum_{d=0}^{10}(17-d)\\
&=17\cdot11-\binom{11}{2}\\
&=132
\end{align}$$

Alternatively,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{d=0}^{10}\sum_{n=0}^{16-d}1&=\sum_{d=0}^{10}(17-d)=17+16+\cdots+7\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^{17}d-\sum_{d=1}^6d\\
&=\binom{18}{2}-\binom{7}{2}\\
&=132
\end{align}$$